# Canvas, z-index и новогодний снежок

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, z-index

Есть вот такое вот демо https://wp-lessons.com/demo/css/padayushhiy-sneg-dlya-sayta-na-html5-canvas.html

Все бы хорошо, но из-за перекрывающего canvas на сайте все ссылки стали не кликабельные. Есть идеи как это исправить?
Можно конечно прописать pointer-events: none; но тогда эффект отбрасывания снега пропадает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initLetItSnow();
});
var initLetItSnow = function() {
  (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  })();
  var flakes = [],
    canvas = document.getElementById("xmas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    mX = -100,
    mY = -100;
  if ($(window).width() < 999) {
    var flakeCount = 125;
  } else {
    var flakeCount = 450;
  }
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  function snow() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
      var flake = flakes[i],
        x = mX,
        y = mY,
        minDist = 250,
        x2 = flake.x,
        y2 = flake.y;
      var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
        dx = x2 - x,
        dy = y2 - y;
      if (dist < minDist) {
        var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
          xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
          ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
          deltaV = force;
        flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
        flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;
      } else {
        flake.velX *= .98;
        if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
          flake.velY = flake.speed
        }
        flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + flake.opacity + ")";
      flake.y += flake.velY;
      flake.x += flake.velX;
      if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
        reset(flake);
      }
      if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
        reset(flake);
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(snow);
  };

  function reset(flake) {
    flake.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    flake.y = 0;
    flake.size = (Math.random() * 3) + 2;
    flake.speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
    flake.velY = flake.speed;
    flake.velX = 0;
    flake.opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
  }

  function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
        size = (Math.random() * 3) + 4,
        speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5,
        opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
      flakes.push({
        speed: speed,
        velY: speed,
        velX: 0,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        size: size,
        stepSize: (Math.random()) / 160,
        step: 0,
        opacity: opacity
      });
    }
    snow();
  };
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mX = e.clientX, mY = e.clientY
  });
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  })
  init();
};
```

```css
#xmas {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
}
a{
  z-index: 9999;
      font-size:30px;
        margin-top:25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="xmas"></canvas>

<center><a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">LINK</a>
</center>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте ссылкам   `position: relative;` без него `z-index` не срабатывает

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initLetItSnow();
});
var initLetItSnow = function() {
  (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  })();
  var flakes = [],
    canvas = document.getElementById("xmas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    mX = -100,
    mY = -100;
  if ($(window).width() < 999) {
    var flakeCount = 125;
  } else {
    var flakeCount = 450;
  }
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  function snow() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
      var flake = flakes[i],
        x = mX,
        y = mY,
        minDist = 250,
        x2 = flake.x,
        y2 = flake.y;
      var dist = Math.sqrt((x2 - x) * (x2 - x) + (y2 - y) * (y2 - y)),
        dx = x2 - x,
        dy = y2 - y;
      if (dist < minDist) {
        var force = minDist / (dist * dist),
          xcomp = (x - x2) / dist,
          ycomp = (y - y2) / dist,
          deltaV = force;
        flake.velX -= deltaV * xcomp;
        flake.velY -= deltaV * ycomp;
      } else {
        flake.velX *= .98;
        if (flake.velY <= flake.speed) {
          flake.velY = flake.speed
        }
        flake.velX += Math.cos(flake.step += .05) * flake.stepSize;
      }
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,255,255," + flake.opacity + ")";
      flake.y += flake.velY;
      flake.x += flake.velX;
      if (flake.y >= canvas.height || flake.y <= 0) {
        reset(flake);
      }
      if (flake.x >= canvas.width || flake.x <= 0) {
        reset(flake);
      }
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(flake.x, flake.y, flake.size, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(snow);
  };

  function reset(flake) {
    flake.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
    flake.y = 0;
    flake.size = (Math.random() * 3) + 2;
    flake.speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5;
    flake.velY = flake.speed;
    flake.velX = 0;
    flake.opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
  }

  function init() {
    for (var i = 0; i < flakeCount; i++) {
      var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width),
        y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height),
        size = (Math.random() * 3) + 4,
        speed = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.5,
        opacity = (Math.random() * 0.5) + 0.3;
      flakes.push({
        speed: speed,
        velY: speed,
        velX: 0,
        x: x,
        y: y,
        size: size,
        stepSize: (Math.random()) / 160,
        step: 0,
        opacity: opacity
      });
    }
    snow();
  };
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mX = e.clientX, mY = e.clientY
  });
  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  })
  init();
};
```

```css
#xmas {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39);
}
a{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
      font-size:30px;
        margin-top:25%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="xmas"></canvas>

<center><a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com/">LINK</a>
</center>
```